# Genera of curves on abelian threefolds, in a fixed homology class

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an abelian $3$-fold over $\mathbb C$ and $\beta\in H_2(X,\mathbb Z)$ a curve class of type $(1,1,d)$ for some $d>0$. This means the following: $\beta$ corresponds to a divisor class $\widehat \beta=c_1(L)\in H^2(\widehat X,\mathbb Z)$ in the cohomology of the dual abelian variety, and the type of $\beta$ is defined to be the type of $L$. In fact $\beta$ is determined by its type up to deformations. I wonder how wildly smooth curves on $X$ can vary within their homology class. The first topological distinction that comes to mind is the following:

**Q.** What are the possible genera of *smooth* curves in class $\beta$?
Is anything along these lines known, at least for low $d$?